# Why is my string not splitting?

Tags: java, string

Example code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Split {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a few words: ");
        String wordsWhole = scan.next();
        String[] wordsSplit = new String[4];
        wordsSplit = wordsWhole.split("//s+");
        System.out.println("Second word: " + wordsSplit[1]);

    }
}
```

The output:

Enter a few words: Why no work

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

at test.Split.main(Split.java:12)

My String isn't splitting into the array like I would expect it to. Any ideas on why this is?

Line 12:

```
        System.out.println("Second word: " + wordsSplit[1]);
```

Comment: Typo: should be `\\s+` and not `//s+`.

Comment: Also, read the javadoc of Scanner.next(), and print the value of `wordsWhole`. Using a debugger to troubleshoot the code would make this kind of problem obvious.

Comment: I did not vote on question (other then to close it), but since it is a typo see first comment I can understand why they down vote..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

- `Scanner.next()` will only return the **first** word (space-separated) in the input, use `Scanner.nextLine()` to get the entire line.
- I'm guessing you're trying to split by spaces. If so, you should use backslashes rather than forward slashes in your regex (`"\\s+"`).
- You don't need to allocate the array before assigning it to the result of the split. Just use `String[] wordsSplit = wordsWhole.split("\\s+");`